# I don't feel that the current answers should be awarded a bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

I asked the question [Add hyperlinks to SWF buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259183/add-hyperlinks-to-swf-buttons) on the 26th October and did not receive a helpful answer and therefore started a +50 bounty on it.

This bounty ended yesterday and I must award the bounty 'as soon as possible' - however I do not feel that either response answers my question and I will explain why.

- Pan's answer, although it is well detailed and I can see a lot of effort has been put into it, it "half answers" my question, as instead of making each location redirect to a different hyperlink, they all redirect to the same one.
- Nbooo's answer should, in my opinion, be a comment instead of an answer as it is very broad without much detail put into it.

What are my options here? Does a bounty have to be awarded?

Comment: Sounds like your question is too broad and should have been closed as such.

Comment: @Servy Please elaborate.

Comment: @TheCodesee It will be automatically awarded by a fixed set of criteria of you choose not to.

Comment: @TheCodesee it will not be auto awarded to an answer that was posted before the bounty was offered, iirc

Comment: @TheCodesee What's there to elaborate on?  It sounds like you're asking for so much information that it cannot be reasonably answered in the scope of an SO answer.  After reading the question, this has only confirmed that suspicion.  You're asking for someone to write an entire tutorial for you.  That's way too broad.

Comment: @Servy So would you suggest I create a question with the answer I have been given (and also linkback to my original question) and say that rather than all locations redirect to the same url, I need them to redirect to different urls?

Comment: @TheCodesee I'm saying that asking an SO question to explain *everything* about a topic is not an appropriate SO question.  You should be using other types of resources for that (books, tutorials, documentation, experimentation, etc.) for those types of questions, and asking a question on SO when you have a *specific* question about a *specific* programming problem.

Comment: Well, it is out of your hands, the community decided.  The "half-answer" got half the bounty, seems appropriate.  If you want to do this again then be sure to improve your question and add another bounty.

Answer (score 8):

Whether you are satisfied or not by the answers, you can not get back the bounty in anyway.

If you do not want to award it to a specific user, [the system  will cope with it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)